# "watching the television" or "watching television"?

Tags: definite-articles

"He was watching the television when I called on him."

When I said this sentence to one of my friends  (an English teacher)  he corrected me saying that the definite article (the) should be omitted. Still, I can't understand why. ?
Actually similar  question has been asked earlier but the answers were so ambiguous.
So I put complete sentence.

Comment: The question has already been asked, I should have checked before answering but at least the answers here are not photocopies of the older ones.

Comment: @todd-wilcox The level of formality is another important variable. In **formal** writing, American authors often omit the definite article. The first example of zero article usage at the end of my post is from an American author. The authors of [this text](https://books.google.com/books?id=UkHMl0uhhZYC&lpg=PA287&dq=%22watching%20television%22&pg=PA287#v=onepage&q=%22watching%20television%22&f=false) are also American.

Comment: As a native AmE speaker (Nebraska), I'm baffled by @ToddWilcox's comment. I would have said that "watching the television" sounded weird to an American ear. Admittedly, using the full word *television* is a bit stuffy anyway, but I would almost always say it without the definite article. Putting *the* in there seems to emphasize that they were staring at the screen itself, regardless of any program that may or may not have been playing. Conjures an image like [this one](https://goo.gl/1yEd1u).

Comment: Can we be clear, you knocked on his door, prolly unexpectedly? You didn’t phone him; nor arrive by arrangement?

Then there’s no difference at all among “television…” or “the television…” or “TV” or “the TV” or “(the) telly” and your friend was trying to make a rule out of something which is in fact, and always will be a matter of personal choice.

Comment: I don't know why, but to my ears "watching television" means watching the content of a transmitted programme, while "watching the television" means keeping an eye on the TV monitor to make sure no-one is stealing it. That is I hear "television" as referring to the broadcast information, and "the television" as referring to the electronic device.

Comment: Retracted close vote, if after 24 hours a question with as many views as this doesn't get closed for being off topic (a duplicate) then it should stay open.

Comment: What spoko & Michael Kay said. I'm reminded of the old joke: "I don't like sex on the television, the antenna pokes me in the eye".

Answer (score 15):

Both versions are acceptable.

If your friend was insisting that you **must** (as opposed to **may**) drop the article, then your friend was simply mistaken.

Having said that..

1. *Watching the television* is more likely in informal than in formal contexts.
2. From discussions on this page and from perusing google books, it seems there may be some difference at least in *informal* usage between American and British English, where American *informal* usage may favor the version *with* the definite article, whereas the British usage may favor the version *without* the definite article in both formal and informal contexts. In fact, there could even be regional differences within the US. (This is how things seem to me at the moment. I admit I don't have a reputable source to back these particular claims up.)

**However**, the two remarks above are only about **tendencies**. In no sense and in no context is the version **with** the definite article 'wrong' or 'unacceptable' or 'bad English'. Indeed, both versions are sometimes found in the same source, sometimes just a few sentences apart (see the examples from published literature at the end of this post).

The discussion below is about some other words as well, not just *(the) television*. This puts the issues in context and you may start to see some regularities better.

Here is the relevant section of [Collins COBUILD English Guides: Articles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0003705617) (pp. 40-42):

> **6.2 Media and communications**
>
> You can refer to systems of mass communication and the media by using a noun with the definite article (or sometimes by using a noun without an article). In this way you can distinguish them from actual objects; 'a radio' will always be a particular object, but 'the radio' could refer to a system, as in this example.
>
> *We gather facts and attitudes from **the press**, **the television** and **the radio**.*
>
> Words in this category are:
>
> (the) television   the box          the telephone      the press      the post (Br)
>   (the) telly            (the) radio    the phone             the paper     the mail (Am)
>   (the) TV               the news       the newspapers   the papers
>
> When referring to television as a form of entertainment or
>   communication, you can use the definite article (which tends to be
>   informal) or no article.
>
> *They go on **the television** and smoke drugs in front of the viewers.*
>
> *He isn't as serious as he is on **television**.*
>
> The abbreviations, 'TV' and 'telly' can be used in the same way, although 'TV' tends to occur without an article in this sense. 'Telly' is an informal alternative; another informal expression is 'the box'
>   (always with *the*).
>
> *I don't want to be seen on **the telly**.*
>   *...anyone whose face appears regularly in newspapers and on **TV***
>   *...a constant background of **telly** or **radio**.*
>
> If someone says 'on the television' it can mean two things: 'physically on' (There's a photo of him on the television'), or 'being broadcast' ('There's a good programme on the television tonight'). If you say 'on television', only the second meaning is possible. (See
>   section 6.4 for more information on 'television'.)
>
> You can refer to radio as a means of communication with either the definite article or no article.
>
> *I just heard her speaking on **the radio**.*
>   *He had already become a climbing spokesman on **radio**.*
>
> When using 'telephone' or 'phone' to refer to a means of communication, you use the definite article.
>
> *A large part of Linda's day is spent on **the telephone**.*
>   *Haig and Nixon are regularly on **the phone** with each other.*
>
> Here we are not thinking of one particular telephone; we are more interested in the form of communication.
>
> There are also the expressions 'by telephone' and 'by phone' in which 'telephone' and 'phone' refer to the system of communication, although there is no article.
>
> *...an attempt to reach her at the camp by **telephone**.*
>
> You speak of 'the newspapers' or 'the papers' when referring to
>   newspapers as a form of media. The meaning is similar to 'the press'.
>
> ***The papers*** are saying how unusual it is.
>   *How would it look in **the papers**?*
>
> Sometimes 'the paper' is also used to mean newspapers generally, not one particular newspaper.
>
> *This is what we read in **the paper**.*
>
> When you use 'post' (American equivalent 'mail') to refer to a system of communication, you use the definite article.
>
> *One morning there arrived through **the post** an amazing letter.*
>
> However, there is also the expression 'by post' which refers to the
>   service.
>
> *He acquired the necessary reference books by **post**.*

Another relevant section is on p. 43:

> **6.4 Forms of entertainment**
>
> When you are talking about someone going to enjoy a form of entertainment you use the definite article with the word for the form of entertainment. Words like this are: 'cinema' (Am 'movies'), 'theatre', 'opera', 'ballet'.
>
> *Let's go to **the movies**.*
>   *You have seen things. You have been to **the opera**, **the ballet**, **the theatre**.*
>
> Here we are not thinking of a particular performance of an opera or ballet, or a particular theatre building, but just of the form of entertainment.
>
> 'Cinema', 'theatre', 'opera', and 'ballet', as well as 'dance', 'film', and 'television', can be used as uncount nouns without an article to refer to the art form.
>
> *...supreme artists of **dance** and **theatre**.*
>   *...a very fine piece of **cinema**.*
>   ***Television*** can be an art medium.

[ComGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582517346) (pp. 269-270) refers to this use of the definite article as **sporadic reference**:

> **(f) Sporadic reference**
>
> **5.33** *The* is sometimes used in reference to an institution of human society. For example, in [1] there are two possible interpretations of *the theatre*:
>
> My sister goes to *the theatre* every month.      [1]
>
> By situational reference, it may mean a particular theatre, say the Criterion Theatre, which my sister attends regularly. But a more likely meaning is that my sister does not necessarily confine her theatre-going to one building: *the theatre* refers, rather, to the theatre as an institution, so that it would be inappropriate to ask, in response to [1]: *Which theatre?* We call this the SPORADIC use of *the*, because reference is made to an institution which may be observed recurrently at various places and times.
>
> There is a similar use of *the news, the radio, the television, the paper(s), the press*, etc, referring to aspects of mass communication:
>
> Did you hear *the ten o'clock news*?
>   What's *in the paper(s)/on the radio/on (the) TV* this evening?
>
> But with *television* or *TV*, there is also the possibility that the article will be omitted (*cf* 5.45).
>
> The concept of sporadic reference also extends to expressions referring to modern transport and communication, such as *the bus*, *the train*, *the post* (esp BrE), *the mail* (esp AmE), *the telephone*:
>
> Mary took *the bus/the train* to London. OR: *a bus/a train*
>   He promised that the letters would be in *the post/the mail* this evening.
>
> In a temporal rather than spatial sense, sporadic reference may even be taken to apply to the optional use of *the* before words referring to seasons (*eg: the winter,* cf 5.47), and to festivals, etc (*the New Year, cf* 5.67).
>
> Note
>
> [**a**] The sporadic use of *the* is in certain instances close to the generic use of *the*. Compare the use of *the theatre* in [1] above with the generic sense of *the theatre* ['drama as an art form'] in [2l:
>
> She's an expert on *(the) (Elizabethan) theatre*.          [2l  
>   Similarly: *the novel, the ballad, (the) drama.*
>
> [**b**] The contrast between situational and sporadic use is manifest in this pair of examples:
>
> *There's a vase of on the television (set)/***television.*
>   *There's an interesting play on (the) television.*

And on pp. 277-278:

> **Noun phrases with sporadic reference**
>
> **5.43** We have already mentioned (cf 5.33) the use of the in noun phrases with 'sporadic' definite reference, as in *the radio, the theatre*. In other cases, however, the sporadic use has become so institutionalized that the article is not used. We distinguish, under this heading, a number of different categories of zero article usage which are 'frozen' as part of idiomatic usage.
>
> **(a) Some 'institutions' of human life and society**
>
> **5.44** Certain nouns have the zero article, especially as complement of *at, in,* and *on* in quasi-locative phrases: thus someone may be *in church*, but not **in library*. We call them 'quasi-locative' because, although they appear to have locative meaning, their function is rather more abstract (*cf: the theatre*, 5.33). In such contexts, nouns such as *college, church*, etc do not refer to actual buildings or places, but to the institutions associated with them: to *be in prison*, for example, is to be a prisoner, not a casual visitor; to *go to sea* is to follow the occupation of a sailor; see the left-hand column below. In the right-hand column we illustrate the same nouns as used with *the* in situational or cataphoric reference:
>
> Compare:
>
> *town*                                  *The* town/*the* city is very old.
>                  *bed*                                     lie down on *the* bed
>   be in      *hospital*                              redecorate *the* hospital
>   go to       *prison, jail*                       walk around *the* prison/*the* jail
>                  *class* (esp AmE)              *The* class works hard.
>
> be at       *school*                                 visit *the* school
>   go to       *sea*                                       look out towards *the* sea
>
> be in/be at *church*                          admire *the* church
>   go to *college*                                     the gates of *the* college
>
> Note
>
> [**a**] Other related phrases are the following, some of which show variation in the use of article:
>
> get out of *bed*
>   during (the) *break/recess*
>   be in/return to *camp*
>   live on/off (the) *campus*
>   be on/off (the) *stage*
>   at (the) *court* [royal palace]; in (the) *court* [law court]; The case was settled out of *court*; take someone to *court*
>   come/go/leave *home*; be (at) *home*; feel at *home*
>
> With *university*, the article is optional in BrE in the expressions *be at/go to (the) university*, whereas AmE requires the definite article (as also with *hospital* in AmE: 'He's in the hospital.').
>
> [**b**] The article is sometimes left out also when the reference is to the building, not the institution:
>
> I walked straight back *into/to school*.
>   She's *at church*, arranging flowers.
>
> In AmE, and increasingly in BrE, the article is often omitted in expressions like:
>
> in the center of *town*, the business part of *town*.
>
> **(b) Means of transport and communication**
>
> **5.45** This type is confined to zero article following *by*; but the same nouns can be used elsewhere with 'sporadic' *the* (*cf* 5.33):
>
> Compare
>                              *bicycle*                  take *the* bicycle
>   travel                *bus*                         be on *the* bus
>   leave      by       *car*                         prefer *the* car
>   come                 *boat*                       choose *the* boat
>   go                      *train*                      take *a/the* train
>                              *plane*                     be on *the* plane
>
> *radio*
>                                                                     *telephone, telex*
>   communicate/communication by     *post* (esp BrE)
>                                                                     *mail* (esp AmE)
>                                                                    *satellite*
>
> Compare:
>
> a talk on *the* radio
>            Jill is on *the* telephone.
>            put a letter in *the* post
>            send it through *the* mail
>            *The* satellite is replacing cable TV.
>
> Also: *by hand*

Just as further evidence that what is written above is correct, note that it is easy to find examples of both *watching television* and *watching the television* in published literature:

*This is to pose our activity in our sitting-rooms, watching **the television**, as an active process of decoding or interpretation.* ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=z7KJAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA70&dq=%22This%20is%20to%20pose%20our%20activity%20in%20our%20sitting-rooms%2C%20watching%20the%20television%2C%20as%20an%20active%20process%20of%20decoding%20or%20interpretation%22&pg=PA70#v=onepage&q=%22This%20is%20to%20pose%20our%20activity%20in%20our%20sitting-rooms,%20watching%20the%20television,%20as%20an%20active%20process%20of%20decoding%20or%20interpretation%22&f=false); note that this appears on the same page in the same source as the first example of *watching television*, below)
*GRANDPA: (Watching **the television**.)* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=tX5yQkm50DoC&lpg=PA1&dq=%22watching%20the%20television%22&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q=%22watching%20the%20television%22&f=false)
*The socio-economically deprived spend a disproportionate time watching **the television**, an indoor activity.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=hRmNWYq5u8AC&lpg=PA330&dq=%22watching%20the%20television%22&pg=PA330#v=onepage&q=%22watching%20the%20television%22&f=false)
*She just sat watching **the television**.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=4WynBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT16&dq=%22watching%20the%20television%22&pg=PT16#v=onepage&q=%22watching%20the%20television%22&f=false)

*It is often assumed (certainly by the broadcasters) that watching **television** is something done by the family together at home.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=z7KJAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA70&dq=%22that%20watching%20television%20is%20something%20done%22&pg=PA70#v=onepage&q=%22that%20watching%20television%20is%20something%20done%22&f=false)
*We may keep watching **television**, but the new technologies involve new rituals of use.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=3E99BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA263&dq=%22We%20may%20keep%20watching%20television%2C%20but%20the%20new%20technologies%20involve%20new%20rituals%20of%20use.%20%22&pg=PA263#v=onepage&q=%22We%20may%20keep%20watching%20television,%20but%20the%20new%20technologies%20involve%20new%20rituals%20of%20use.%20%22&f=false)
*So viewers are already accustomed to watching **television** in nontraditional ways.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=-NDa5MdXIzwC&lpg=PT320&dq=%22already%20accustomed%20to%20watching%20television%20in%22&pg=PT320#v=onepage&q=%22already%20accustomed%20to%20watching%20television%20in%22&f=false)
*Professor Sigman expresses concerns about the amount of time spent watching **television**.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=SfTnWUzIMygC&lpg=PA45&dq=%22watching%20television%22&pg=PA45#v=onepage&q=%22watching%20television%22&f=false)

Comment: The newest citation? The one that starts with "The socio-economically" Has this line immediately below it *"The poorest spend around 11 hours a week more than the richest watching TV"* Admit it, the instances where the definite article is omitted when we refer to watching television programmes is far greater than those with.  :)

Comment: Oh, I admit it :). (Well, I don't know about **far** greater, especially in the US; see  Todd Wilcox's comment, above. Somewhat tangentially, I still think that what's true for *TV* is not necessarily true for *television*, as Collins COBUILD says as well.) That's not the question, though. The question is whether *He was watching the television when I called on him* is an acceptable sentence in Standard English. And I say it is. Maybe dropping the *the* would be more common, but it is acceptable with the *the*, too. At the end of the day, do you disagree?

Comment: I think the question of TV or television is irrelevant, "The TV is on" vs "The television is on" are both correct, but here we're talking about the device.

Comment: "They go on **the television** and smoke drugs in front of the viewers." That does not sound right to my ears. It's reminiscent of "I went on the google and searched the tubes" -- it sounds like an eye-rolling teenager making fun of unsavvy adults.

Comment: This answer does not explain to OP *why* they were corrected.

Comment: @sirjonsnow Well, my point is that they should not have been corrected in the first place; the sentence was fine as it was. I thought once I said that much, I don't really have to add, 'You were corrected because your friend mistakenly thought your sentence was not acceptable English. But your friend was wrong.' But OK, I'll add that...

Comment: As a USA-based person, I actually disagree with Todd's comment. It actually sounds odd (to me) to hear "watching *the* television". That seems to focus on the device rather than the content, as @Mari-LouA notes above. "watching television" implies that you're watching a program. "watching *the* television" doesn't necessarily imply the same thing. Again, IMHO. On the other hand, it's not *wrong* necessarily either.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Thanks for the input; that's very interesting, and it suggests there may be regional differences within the US.

Comment: Another American here; in agreement with @GalacticCowboy. "Watching television" has a different meaning (at least here in the US) than "Watching *the* television". The former means you're viewing a TV program(me). The latter means you're observing the television receiver itself (perhaps it's on fire). Not often used.

Comment: @nerdfever-com Thank you for that input!

Comment: Watching the television means looking at the actual device, not what is showing on television to me. And I am not American.

Comment: Although I'm American rather than British, I watch a number of British television shows, and "the telly" is essentially always used with the definite article.  Otherwise, I think the use of the article with "radio" but not "television" relates to the fact that the broadcast-viewing device is referred to as a "television *set*", but the broadcast-listening device is usually referred to as a "radio" rather than a "radio receiver" or "radio set".

Answer (score 9):

I prefer saying

> I'm watching [a programme/film/movie on] TV
>   *ergo*
>   I'm watching television

If you are watching *the* TV it sounds like the television set (now that's an oldie) is being active and is doing something. It's possible... but unlikely.

We normally watch something that is in movement, that requires our attention.

Authoritative source, [English Oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/television), I was prepared to concede victory if I saw it had any instances where the definite article was used, instead there is not one example. Interesting!

> - ‘Dan was sitting on the settee **watching television**’
> - ‘Norman was **on television** yesterday’
> - ‘I thought very little of it … as I walked through the house and lay down on the sofa to watch television.’
> - ‘She lay on her mother's sofa, watching television and eating chocolates, ….’
> - ‘I'm home today, just lying here, **watching daytime television** and surfing.’
> - ‘You can't keep sitting on the sofa all day, watching daytime television and eating chocolate chip cookies.’
> - ‘I'm not cut out to spend evenings on the sofa watching television and going to bed early.’
> - ‘Before the interview, Depp had been **watching cable television** in the next room.’
> - ‘**Most television**, particularly network programs, has gone from vast wasteland to empty universe.’
> - ‘Folks at the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention are watching daytime television.’

Comment: Don't you think that there's a difference here between *TV* and *television*? I would say that the definite article is far less likely in front of *TV* than in front of *television*. The passage from *Collins COBUILD* I cited in my post would also seem to say that.

Comment: I [watch the BBC](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=pyjnWueXG8WYsgH1uryQBQ&q=%22watch+the+BBC%22&oq=%22watch+the+BBC%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.4579.7145.0.7633.2.2.0.0.0.0.141.259.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.258...0i67k1j0i7i30k1.0.MQeOF7md3eA) but I don't [watch ITV](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=sSjnWr2HFImugQbp6KnABA&q=%22watch+ITV%22&oq=%22watch+ITV%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i7i30k1l9.45298.48264.0.49542.10.10.0.0.0.0.181.1288.0j8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.8.1287...0i131k1j0i67k1j0i131i67k1j0i7i10i30k1.0.47QzZfR2xUg)  ... definite articles are eccentric little things.

Comment: Haha, that they are...

Comment: From OED:

***on (the) television:*** broadcast or transmitted by television; appearing in a television programme.

1929    *He would have to leave it to the honor of the watchers not to smoke while the bouts were **on the television**.*
1938    *I reviewed this film three weeks ago when I saw it **on television**.*
1965    *You could get a job **on the television**.*
1980     *That ghastly woman with the teeth who's always **on the television**.*
2009    *One in five people had found out about food intolerances from a celebrity interview in a magazine or **on television**.*

Comment: "The" would also be used used if you were keeping watch or guarding it.  For example, carrying one from your car to your apartment and you leave someone else with it for a few minutes, "Watch the television, I'll be right back."

Comment: @Mari-LouA Expand the abbreviations and it's much less eccentric: you watch the British Broadcasting Corporation but you don't watch Independent Television.

Comment: Also from OED: in the meaning '1 b. The activity or occupation of broadcasting or transmitting on television; the television system or service as a whole; television as a medium of communication or as a form of art or entertainment.', they give (among others) the following example:  *I have sometimes thought how different life might have been at Haworth if only they had had **the television**, and Tide, and a Morris Minor.* Definitely most of their examples are without the article, but I think this is because they come from more formal sources, where the zero article is more likely.

Comment: @sirjonsnow But that's really a different meaning of *television*, namely, one that refers to an actual physical object, an individual electronic device. The meaning under discussion, however, is different. It is (as the OED puts it) 'the activity or occupation of broadcasting or transmitting on television; the television system or service as a whole; television as a medium of communication or as a form of art or entertainment'.

Comment: @linguisticturn I think sirjonsnow is saying that the definite article is more common when we consider the television as a device, as a piece of electronic equipment. The me "watching" the TV move around the house, sort of thing.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes, and I believe that's why the teacher gave that correction to OP's statement.

Comment: @linguisticturn - I believe that's why the teacher corrected OP, that OP should make it clear they were watching a program on the television and not the television itself.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh, I agree with *that*. I just think that's not the context of this particular question. When we say *He was watching the television when I called on him*, it seems to me that by *television* we normally mean 'a form of entertainment or communication' rather than 'a device for viewing TV broadcasts'.  Indeed, if it was important to make it clear that he was watching a *particular* TV device (e.g. one we gave him as a Christmas gift), I think most of us would use a different phrasing... wouldn't we?

Comment: @sirjonsnow See my comment to Mari-LouA immediately above.

Comment: @sirjonsnow But there is a bottom line here, and it is this: **in the intended context of the question**, is  *He was watching the television when I called on him* an acceptable English sentence or not? I categorically say that it is.  I agree that the version **without** the *the* is definitely acceptable, but I insist that the version **with** the *the* is **also** acceptable.  Do you disagree?

Comment: @mari-lou-a Same question as the one I just posed to sirjonsnow...

Comment: @linguisticturn it's grammatical.

Comment: @linguisticturn - the OP asked why they were corrected, not just if it's a valid sentence in the English language.  "Eats, shoots, and leaves." is a great example of a valid sentence not conveying the proper message.

Comment: @sirjonsnow Hi, if you could post your comments to linguisticum underneath their post then you two can bash it out between yourselves. Thanks!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - done; I was stressing that you addressed OP's question, while the other answer didn't

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you...! I was pretty sure that, fundamentally, we don't really disagree. :)

Answer (score 3):

The two different phrases have subtly different meanings. Both may be correct, depending on what meaning you want to communicate.

- The form *watching television* refers to the uncountable noun “television”, which implies one is referring to the (uncountable and, in principle, unending) *stream of content* that the medium of television provides.
- The form *watching the television* refers to “the television”, a singular device sitting in the room, which implies one is engaged with *that specific device* and giving it attention, as distinct from other televisions in other places.

Yes, these both encompass pretty much the same behaviour. But they communicate a different emphasis in each case. Choose accordingly.

(Inspired by [a comment from @supercat](http:////english.stackexchange.com/questions/444163/watching-the-television-or-watching-television/444272#comment1067468_444241))

Answer (score 0):

The most common way an American would say that is;

"When I called him, he was watching TV."

Or to a lesser degree;

"He was watching TV when I called."

A TV was ordered, and needs to be picked up at "K-Mart";

"You need to go to K-Mart and pick up the TV."

Or

"Could you go to K-Mart and pick up the TV for me?"

If the television (brand/model) had not been picked-out yet, you would say, "a TV", instead of "the TV."

"Hey kids! Stop jumping around near the TV. Someone's going to fall and get hurt!"

"Where do you want the TV, in this corner, or that one?"

"Do you want to watch TV?"

"Yes Officer, someone broke in (my house/apartment) and took my television"

"Could you put these flowers on top of the TV?"

"Where did you put the flowers?" "They're on the TV"

..."They're right next to the TV."

"where's my TV?"

If someone was in the other room, they might say "television" for clarity.

Comment: Note that the OP has *called **on** him*, which in this context means *paid him a visit* or *dropped in on him* (see e.g. [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/call_on)).

Comment: It would be interesting if you could comment on the particular sentence the OP is talking about, which in American idiom would be: *He was watching the television when I dropped in on him.* Concentrate on the definite article in front of *television*. Do you think this is an acceptable English sentence **as written**, or do you think that we **must** drop the definite article to make it acceptable?

Comment: @linguisticturn: I would interpret the sentence with the article as having a *different meaning* from the one without.  The form with the article would be correct if, e.g. "he" had just repaired the television set, plugged it in, and turned it on, and he was watching it to observe whether it would start smoking or otherwise malfunction when I dropped in on him.  If, however, his focus was on the programming rather than on the behavior of the set, then the article should be omitted.